# How to set Spring integration gemfire port

Tags: spring-integration

Im using gemfire as metadatastore

```
    <gfe:cache/>
<gfe:replicated-region id="region" />
 <bean id="metadataStore" class="org.springframework.integration.metadata.PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore"/>

<bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>

            <bean id="filterAllFiles" class="id.lsa.scb.spring.integration.filter.EntireFileFilter">
                <property name="adrUtil" ref="pojoUtil"/>
            </bean>

            <bean id="acceptOnceFilter"
                  class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter">

                <constructor-arg name="store" ref="metadataStore"/>
                <constructor-arg name="prefix" value="test-"/>
                <property name="flushOnUpdate" value="true"/>

            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but got error :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gemfireCache': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is com.gemstone.gemfire.SystemConnectException: Unable to find a free port in the membership-port-range
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1590)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
at org
```

1. How to solve that? Can i set the port manualy?Can i set the port manualy?
2. How to read metadata from gemfire manualy, can i use something like sql query?

Answer (score 0):

That is more question to Gemfire. Not sure where you can find their forum, mailing list or any other support.

The message

> Unable to find a free port in the membership-port-range

is for this `membership-port-range` property, which you can configure in the `gemfire.properties`: http://gemfire702.docs.pivotal.io/7.0.2/userguide/reference/topics/gemfire_properties.html#gemfire_properties

I don't see by your config that you really use `GemfireMetadataStore`.

I think you can read that metadata manually and even use queries. `GemfireMetadataStore` is fully based on the `Region<String, String>` injected: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/gemfire.html#gemfire-metadata-store

Comment: Thanks Artem for the clue.  Finally i use redis for metadata store. Yes that implementation still using default spring integration metadatastore , its my bad understanding.